# What are some good books about the philosophy of mind?

Tags: reference-request, philosophy-of-mind, cognitive-sciences, functionalism

I took a class covering some problems of philosophy of mind last term; On free will and mental causation. And I'm reading Kim's *philosophy of mind* But since my professor was taught by Kim, I want to read other books on philsophy of mind, especially on machine functionalism which have different point of view from Kim. Is there any proper book on philsophy of mind or cognitive science for those who are like me?

Comment: do you know what is the difference between phil of mind, neurophilosophy and cognitive science, except that the latter is more about experiments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kim's book is very good. There are other general intros to the mind/body problem like [Jaworski](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1444333682) or [Heil](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0415283566).

At some point you'd want to read some of the primary sources. This [collection](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0199253838), also by Heil contains many seminal papers.

The "[contemporary debates](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1405117613)" series is good for cutting edge discussion, but tends to be quite advanced.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a paper and not a book, but one of the most influential in this area.

[Empiricism and the Philosophy of Mind (1956)](http://ditext.com/sellars/epm.html)

by Wilfrid Sellars